# Unity3D nothing but distortion when playing audio clips

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I'm having a lot of trouble with playing audio clips. I suspect it has something to do with update playing my clip from the start every time it executes the block of code that sends the clip to the audio source. Below is a 'solution' but the fact that it works doesn't even make sense to me. If I just put the audio.play() in the main if statement without checking whether it's less than the audio clip length, I hear nothing but a quiet distortion.

```
void Update()
{
switch(weatherState)
    {
    case WeatherStates.Sunny:

        break;
    case WeatherStates.Rain:
        Rain();
        break; 
    case WeatherStates.Snow:

        break;

    case WeatherStates.ThunderStorm:

        break; 
    }

}


void Rain()
{
    if(timeScript.hourOfWeatherEvent != 0)
    {

        if(timeScript.hourCount >= timeScript.hourOfWeatherEvent)
        {
            rain.SetActive(true); 
            if(soundCount < weatherSounds[0].length)
            {
                soundCount++; 
                audio.clip = weatherSounds[0];
                audio.Play ();
            }
            timeScript.durationOfWeatherEvent -= Time.deltaTime * timeScript.timeSpeed;

            if(timeScript.durationOfWeatherEvent <= 0)
            {
                rain.SetActive(false); 
                timeScript.durationOfWeatherEvent = 0; 
                timeScript.hourOfWeatherEvent = 0; 
                weatherState = WeatherStates.Sunny; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: quiet distortion sounds like its being started every frame of the update, you should use a boolean or check if the audio is playing before you play it

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I thought was happening. I changed the if to if(audio.clip == null) and now there is no problem.